# Break text of submit button when text exceeds container

Tags: css

I'm having an issue when the text of a submit button is really long and it exceeds the width of its parent container on mobile.

```
<input type="submit" value="This is a submit button with a very long line of text which causes issues">
```

I'd like to break the line of the submit button when the button width exceeds the width of its parent container but it seems like this is not possible at all?

For the moment the width of the button doesn't expand the parent container anymore with the following CSS

```
.parent-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    width: 100%;
}
```

However this cuts off a part of the submit button text which instead should be placed on a new line of text.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `width 100%;` will only work if parent has a width in px, vw, rem, em, otherwise it will do however it wants. So as you did not set any width of the parent it will grow anyway

Comment: Please add in a code snippet the whole HTML and CSS that reproduces your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS -

```
input[type="submit"]{
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

width 100%; will only work if parent has a width in px, vw, rem, em, otherwise it will do however it wants. So as you did not set any width of the parent it will grow anyway.

After just add `white-space: normal;` to your input to make it break word.

```css
.parent-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

input[type="submit"]{
    width: 100%;
    white-space: normal;
}

.width-fix{
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <input type="submit" value="This is a submit button with a very long line of text which causes issues">
</div>

<div class="parent-container width-fix">
  <input type="submit" value="This is a submit button with a very long line of text which causes issues">
</div>
```

Comment: Adding the `white-space` style to the input was indeed the solution. Thanks for your reply as well